# Supporting difference screen size in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing a UI which uses icons and custom circular views. According to the documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
I have created separate drawable folders for hdpi, ldpi....xxxhdpi. Also created layout-sw660dp and layout-sw720dp. The scaling of the icons are working fine in Nexus 5x and Google nexus 10 inch tablet, but it is not scaling for LG G3 device. Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong. Below is a sample of my landscape layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/topLayout"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:keepScreenOn="true">

<com.facedetection.kv.facedetection.ui.camera.CameraSourcePreview
    android:id="@+id/preview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    >
    <!--android:onClick="onClickOnSurfaceView"        -->

    <com.facedetection.kv.facedetection.ui.camera.GraphicOverlay
        android:id="@+id/faceOverlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</com.facedetection.kv.facedetection.ui.camera.CameraSourcePreview>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/controls"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/preview"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/custom_rounded_view_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_rounded_view_height"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        >

        <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/savedImageView"
            android:src="@drawable/hugh"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:riv_border_width="5dip"
            app:riv_border_color="#333333"
            app:riv_mutate_background="true"
            app:riv_oval="true"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"

        >




        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/cameraClick"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_panorama_fish_eye_black_24dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/switch_camera"/>

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/custom_circle_view_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_circle_view_height"
            android:layout_gravity="left">

            <com.facedetection.kv.facedetection.CustomView.CustomCircleView
                android:id="@+id/leftEyeView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/custom_circle_layout_margin"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                custom:circleColor="@color/md_blue_A700"
                custom:circleLabel=""
                custom:labelColor="@color/md_black_1000"
                custom:circleTextSize="@dimen/custom_circle_text_size"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/custom_circle_view_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_circle_view_height"
            >

            <com.facedetection.kv.facedetection.CustomView.CustomCircleView
                android:id="@+id/smileyView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/custom_circle_layout_margin"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                custom:circleColor="@color/md_blue_A700"
                custom:circleLabel=""
                custom:labelColor="@color/md_black_1000"
                custom:circleTextSize="@dimen/custom_circle_text_size"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/custom_circle_view_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_circle_view_height"
            >

            <com.facedetection.kv.facedetection.CustomView.CustomCircleView
                android:id="@+id/rightEyeView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/custom_circle_layout_margin"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                custom:circleColor="@color/md_blue_A700"
                custom:circleLabel=""
                custom:labelColor="@color/md_black_1000"
                custom:circleTextSize="@dimen/custom_circle_text_size"
                />

        </LinearLayout>




        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/cameraSwitch"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_switch_camera_black_24dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/switch_camera"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>



</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is the landscape view only you should have that as a qualifier as well, so it would be for example, layout-sw720dp-land and layout_sw720dp-port for the portrait view.  This will cause this layout to only occur when the device is in landscape mode or portrait mode respectively.

Secondly, make sure you arent using the same icon in the drawables folders.  They need to increase in size to correlate with the folder (I assume you have this already if the other screens are working).

Not sure if this helps.

Comment: I also removed the following from the landscape mode which was not there in my portrait. 
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

Comment: Great! also you can use these same qualifiers for those as well.  So you could set an @dimen/activity_vertical_margin to only to be used in landscape modes on any device or you could set it to only use the dimen in landscape mode when the smallest width is a certain amount.  This is done in nearly the same way, and in android studio is just adding a new resource and clicking the qualifier.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this [library](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html?hl=es)

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <ImageView
         app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
         app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
         app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
         app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%"/>
 </android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>
```